# Moving a Point on a Plane based on provided UVMap data

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, transforms, height-map

[Here is the Project file I'm working off of.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13yhzTOOGikBNvGN9f3HSrxgnsTG9hBV0/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying to instance an object on top of a map of mine, that will then move according to how I move and scale the UV's from the provided map. The main issue I'm running into is that when I move the UV map around, the point moves in unexpected and seemingly random directions.
I know that what I'm trying to do should be a relatively easy thing to accomplish, I just have no idea where I'm going wrong. Any help at all is appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the map and an object I'm trying to instance:
[image: Ico sphere is the object I'm trying to move around]

And the Ico sphere not moving with the heightmap:
[image: not moving]

Here's the important parts of the node tree:
[image]

Comment: I can't recreate the problem shown in the second image.  When I set the nodes to the same parameters you've shown (which is how it's set in the file), the XY position of the icosphere is completely different relative to the height map grid; its Z pos is the height of the grid.  Overall, this seems like an overly complicated way to achieve anything you want to achieve, and I can't follow the reasoning behind certain decisions, nor your intended controls.  Why not just move a UV sphere around and project it down onto the heightmap?